# Having Problems with back to home in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i have one page which have some div with different id for move between div , i move to one of div by panel but when i return to main page list of item(panel) does not work. this is Part of the code.... What should I do

```
<div data-role="page" id="main" data-theme="a">
 <div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay"           id="listpanel">
   <ul data-role="listview" style="float:right">
        <li>
            <a href="#page1">item1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#page2">item2</a>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>  
<div data-role="header">
<h1>mainheader</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" id="listpanel">
    <ul data-role="listview" style="float:right">
        <li>
            <a href="#page1">item1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#page2">item2</a>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="header">
<h1>item1</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">
    <li><a href="#listpanel">list</a></li>
    <li><a href="#main">mainpage</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Content</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" id="listpanel">
    <ul data-role="listview" style="float:right">
        <li>
            <a href="#page1">item1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#page2">item2</a>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="header">
<h1>item2</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">
    <li><a href="#listpanel">list</a></li>
    <li><a href="#main">mainpage</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try to replicate the problem with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: Use different id for panel in each page or just use external panel offered in JQM 1.4